# Resource names in Android Studio are turning red

Tags: android, android-resources, android-studio-2.1

I am a new developer to Android. I have been writing an extension to a program that has been developed in Eclipse, but because Android Studio is familiar to me, I am migrating the project to Android Studio.

The problem is in the labels file (which accesses resources):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:ns1="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2"     
xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.android.com/tools"    
xmlns:ns3="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/">
<attr format="reference" name="drawerArrowStyle"/>
```

(code snippet)

I found out that the first one is xliff, the second looks familiar (being the tools schema which i find in layout files usually) and the last one for correct use of namespaces in xml. The errors are the URIs themselves.

As I'm a newbie when it comes to Android, I would like to know what is happening here also. When you mouse over the error, it indicates that you need to look in Settings-> Languages and Frameworks -> Schemas and DTDs.

This is the dialog that you get when you are mapping an external resource.

[Map External Resource Dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXXqT.png)

I'm running Android Studio version 2.1.2 with API22 which is the min version that has been used for the project.